# Declare Function to Play Sound in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit, function-declaration

Okay so I had an Excel tool that would open a userform and have the option to play a sound based on selections and requiring the user to select the source of the tones. This was working beautifully in 32-bit, but I recently updated to 64-bit and learned that the code is not all the same.

My original code was this, sitting outside of any Subs on the UserForm (General Declarations):

```
    Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
      Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
      ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
```

I have been looking around online and seen a lot of stuff about PtrSafe Functions and variables as LongPtr so I tried using this code based on what I've seen samples of online:

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As StrPtr, _
  ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If
```

The error I'm getting is "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined" which highlights this part of the code under `#If VBA7 And Win64 Then`...

```
Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As StrPtr, _
  ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr) As LongPtr
```

I'm at a complete loss. Is there a reference that I need to check off that I'm not aware of? Will that cause compatibility issues when someone else uses the tool? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StrPtr` is a function, not a data type. All  you need is:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: I had actually tried that code as well but I get a different error: "Compile Error: Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules."

I thought this might have something to do with the fact that the code is located inside the UserForm, but I tried putting it in the public space of the Workbook code and get the same issue. It actually won't even let me save when it's in the Workbook code.

Comment: @Reece You should just be able to change to `Private Declare ...` on both of your `Declare Function` statements.

Comment: That solved the issue and has been tested on 32 and 64 bit. I've edited the answer to include Private as part of the Declare statements.